# Mule - Flow executed successfully, first time only, but not after that. Why/solution?

Tags: mule, execution, mule-studio

I am new to Mule.

I have written java code(CreateObject)for creation of some object on Server end. 
I pass few parameters to Mule from client end HTML form like Object Name, Object Size, Object Host name etc. 
Mule further call java code(CreateObject) and creates Object on Server end and return response that Object created successfully.

In Mule, the flow is running fine, for the first time, but is not executing successfully during second time.

Following is my Mule flow:

```
<flow name="Object-Create" doc:name="Object-Create">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8146/Create" contentType="text/html" doc:name="Service-Request">
    <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer doc:name="FormParam-To-Mule"/>
    <not-filter>
        <wildcard-filter pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
    </not-filter>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Form-Display"  message="#[payload]" />
    <custom-transformer class="Objectclient.CreateObject" doc:name="Call-Server"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Output-Display" message="#[payload]"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
```

When i restarted the service, then flow executed successfully(Object is created on server end) for the first time but second/Third/Fourth time, it doesn't. There is no error given second time by flow.

When i run PSVM java code independently twice then Object creates successfully on server end, both the time/everytime.

Could anyone suggest what could be the reason in Mule which is not letting me to accomplish other requests than first and solution for the same ?

Comment: the filters act in such a way that the flow is not executed further if the condition is not satisfied . Please check the inputs. (Hoping to have understood you query as the second time the flow gets started with no errors but no output.)

Comment: is 'Form-Display' only logged once?

Comment: Yes, Form-Display is logged once only for watching forms parameters received in web page. The filter i added much later after searching,  when i see this warning ->  WARN  2014-01-24 09:39:45,228 [[prjvmwarej].http.request.dispatch.8146.01] org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnector: No receiver found with secondary lookup on connector: connector.http.mule.default with URI key: http://localhost:8146/favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

Though this is probably not your issue, I suggest you:

- move the `http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer` after the inbound endpoint as there's no need to run it for the favicon requests you're filtering out,
- drop the useless and obsolete `echo-component`.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed and dropped above components, even also removed filters, but i find same issue(doesn't execute other time) while executing flow. 
When i restart service i am able to create object(a virtual disk) on server but can't create two one after another. Just in morning i was able to successfully execute flow twice, but third time it does not create object on server. I hope this may be server side issue but Administrator said that i have all access rights and i am admin so it should be issue in my Mule application. Could you suggest more add or del, as i am stuck :(

Comment: In addition to above, Server Side error i found is ""Permission to perform this operation was denied. You do not hold privilege on datastore"". But as i am able to create after each restart of Mule and independently running PSVM so i could not assure that it is server side issue only and Administrator also said the same. In Java code, SOAP Web service client is made which calls https service operations. Java code is running everytime as it run firstly. The logging within java code is running all fine from initial to end.

Comment: I don't totally understand what's going on: when "things" don't work, does the full fully executes or not? Is the `Output-Display` logger called all the time or does the execution blocks in `Objectclient.CreateObject`? If the Execution blocks in `Objectclient.CreateObject`, then the issue is in this code and we would need to see it to try to fix it.

Comment: It is System.out.print() in between code which shows code is executing till end. Code is like -> public String CVM() { try { connect(); createVMObject();} catch (SOAPFaultException sfe) . Check next comment for brief about next

Comment: In Connect method, trustAllHttpsCertificates(); HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv); vmService = new VmService();  vmPort = vmService.getVmPort(); httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(vmPort).getConduit(); TLSClientParameters tlsCP = new TLSClientParameters(); tlsCP.setDisableCNCheck(true); httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsCP);
vmPort.login(serviceContent.getSessionManager(),
            userName,
            password, null);

Comment: Above you have general idea what process is going on in Java code which includes, trusting all certificates, make service client and calling operation on port. It connects to server everytime but can't create object second time. What could be the reason? any session need to destory, but i am nullyfying all objects too.